# Wordpress mod_rewrite and custom rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got the default Wordpress .htaccess which is configured on the structure of post names (http://exampleblog.com/dev/the-post-slug)

This is the .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>   
# END WordPress
```

What I need to is that in a URL like http://exampleblog.com/dev/the-post-slug I could add my own sulfixes, like http://exampleblog.com/dev/the-post-slug/mydemo, and I want to point to that something that now is http://exampleblog.com/dev/wp-content/themes/the-theme/my-custom-folder

So I need to access this URL http://exampleblog.com/dev/the-post-slug/mydemo to show the content of this real patch  http://exampleblog.com/dev/wp-content/themes/the-theme/my-custom-folder and I just can't find a way

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you could just make "the-post-slug" a parent page of "mydemo" and the url is automatically done how you want.

For the second part, you could write a shortcode that lets you load in content from a different page (like with file_get_contents, an iframe, or even just an actual redirect if you don't care if the URL stays the same, just that it exists to get the user where they need to be).  In the case of a redirect code, you'd be better off with using a hook though, since a shortcode could be run after headers are already sent to the browser.

That way you won't have to worry about your extra .htaccess rules being overwritten by WordPress, and it will all be manageable in the future with the CMS, rather than having to edit any files.

Comment: And as an added bonus with the shortcode method, users can actually find the content in searches, whereas if you use .htaccess to try to catch and redirect outside of WordPress, it won't really even know the pages exist.

Comment: If I create a the-post-slug parent of mydemo, it'll break the this-post-slug on Wordpress, because the path is not really there.

About your other suggestion, it unfortunately won't work because I want this to be indexed by Google http://exampleblog.com/dev/the-post-slug/mydemo

Thanks anyway

Comment: This plugin may help: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/ 

Or you can dig through http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite which will allow you to add rewrite rules directly through WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this in the permalinks settings? `Settings → Permalinks`. Looks like you may be looking for something like: `/%category%/%postname%/`.

More info on this, as well as working directly with .htaccess with Wordpress URLs can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I actually like the structure /%postname%/, the problem is that I want to put after the /%postname%/ a custom rule to redirect me to a folder outside Wordpress, and I just can't find a way to do it, I've tried with some techniques show at this portion of the Wordpress Codex, without success